# Bizarrer perl behavior with glob

Tags: perl, list, glob

```
use strict;
use warnings;
#only linux
#use diagnostics;

# - - - - - - - - - - - -- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
sub in_function {
    my $file = shift;

    glob($file) or die ("$file file was not found\n"); #this fails second time called

    # this is ok second time called
    #my @dummy = glob($file) or die ("$file file was not found\n");
}
# - - - - - - - - - - - -- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
my $file = "/tmp/file1*.pdf";
glob($file) or die ("$file file was not found\n");
in_function($file);
$file = "/tmp/file2*.pdf";
glob($file) or die ("$file file was not found\n");
in_function($file);
```

First glob is fine
First in_function glob is fine
Second glob is fine
Second in_function glob fails
Why do I need to assign glob to a variable when called within a function?

Comment: What use would `glob` be if you did not use the return value? `glob or die` is not likely a useful way to use `glob`.

Comment: Seemed simplest way to check for existence of wildcarded filename. Open to suggestion.

Comment: It seems like an XY-problem, in a way. Like a solution that has gone one step too far in the wrong direction, and you need to take a few steps back to find a good solution. First off, if it was me, I would rather check exact file names with a loop, if possible. And is checking for the existence of a file name the best way to check that whatever you wanted to check has happened? `glob` can give a false positive for file existence. Try for example to remove `*` from the string, and you will see that you always get a match.

Comment: @Paul: but it doesn't check for existence of wildcarded filename.  try `glob('{a,b}')` for instance

Comment: file_a_v1.txt
file_b.txt
file_c_v3.txt
Need to know file a, b, c exist. file_a*.txt file_b*.txt file_c*.txt
Do not know the versions, just that a, b, c must exist on fs.

Comment: I see. Might need to first get all files, pull off version extension, then compare lists. List of files on fs vs list of files that must exist...uggh

Comment: @ysth: That's misleading. `glob` will return only the names of files that exist *unless* it contains *no wildcard* `*` or `?` *or character class* `[abc]`. While that means that a simple file name with no metacharacters will just be echoed (e.g. `glob 'abc'` will return `abc` regardless of whether it exists) you can force a directory check by putting one of the characters in a character class, like `glob '[a]bc'`

Comment: @Paul: If your file names are realistic, I would suggest `glob 'file_[abc]*.txt'` but you would have to check the resulting list separately to ensure that *all* of the `a`, `b`, and `c` variants were present.

Comment: @Borodin: not misleading; I'm assuming the pattern here comes from user input (or why validate it?) so it needs to be robust.  I would do `() = grep -f, glob $pattern or die`

Comment: @ysth: That's fine in this context, but *"[glob] doesn't check for existence of wildcarded filename"* just isn't true.

Comment: @ysth: In fact the reverse is closer to actuality: `glob` will check the existence of files *only* if the pattern you pass contains wildcards - meaning `*`, `?` and a character class `[...]`

Answer (score 2):

From [`perldoc -f glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)

> In scalar context, glob iterates through such filename expansions, returning undef when the list is exhausted.

The following will do the trick:

```
() = glob($file) 
   or die ...;
```

But you problably want to know what the matches are, so you can use

```
my @matches = glob($file) 
   or die ...;
```

Comment: When called as such: glob() or die, this is what context within a function?
When called as such: glob() or die, this is what context when not within a function?

Comment: @Paul it is scalar context in both cases. Note that first call to glob in scalar context starts iterator.

Comment: Missing something or not explaining. glob() or die works fine when NOT within a function call. It can be called repeatedly and works as expected. So the two files above exist. Three times glob is called (main, function, main = success) fourth time in function failure. The behavior within the function differ from the behavior not within a function.

Comment: P.S. () = glob($file)  changes it to list context?

Comment: All I want to know is if any file matching wildcard exists, if not die.

Comment: @Paul `my @matches = glob($file) or die ..` would be idiomatic way in perl, and you don't have to look at `@matches` if you don't want to.

Comment: @Paul: no difference in a function or not, but *each* glob operator in the source is a separate iterator, so you won't see the problem unless you loop back in some way.

Comment: But it's not a scalar context, glob's being called in a void context. Edit: I see my mistake `&x or die` is scalar context due to the `or`... I think.

Comment: @ytsh: The glob in the function and its iterator is being "reused"( was not assigned)? That's what I was looking for. "Still unsure" but makes sense. Any links or info on why...more general perl question now.

Comment: @amphetamachine https://eval.in/195759

Comment: @Paul, yes, `() = glob($file)` calls glob in list context and, if the whole expression is in scalar context such as provided by `or`, returns the count of elements returned by glob.

Comment: @amphetamachine: Void context is generally seen as a special case of scalar context. Very few functions change their behaviour other than between *list* and *scalar/void* context.