# How is the glob iterator stored between function calls?

Tags: perl, iterator

I made the following comment on an answer to my [earlier question about `glob`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25935585):

> glob() or die works fine when NOT within a function call. It can be called repeatedly and works as expected. So the two files above exist. Three times glob is called (main, function, main = success) fourth time in function failure. The behavior within the function differ from the behavior not within a function.

[ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth) responded:

> no difference in a function or not, but each glob operator in the source is a separate iterator, so you won't see the problem unless you loop back in some way

In the following code, why/where/how is the iterator from the `glob` operator saved between calls? Why is it not going out of scope? I know what it is doing, but can't see how it is behaving in memory.

```
sub in_function {
    my $file = shift;

    glob($file) or die ("$file file was not found\n"); #this fails second time called
}
```

Comment: This question attempts to continue a non-existent "thread". Every post on Stack Overflow should be unique

Comment: always use glob in list context in reusable code, unless you are certain you will exhaust the iterator before trying to start a new iteration

Comment: isn't glob linked to `glob(3)`? if so, it depends on your implementation of glob.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S.: no, it is the perl layer above that that presents an iterator that he is having an issue with

Comment: @Borodin I agree, the question would probably be better without the comments from the OP's previous post. Simply "why/where/how is the iterator from the glob operator saved between function calls?" seems like a much better question.

Comment: @Paul: Stack Overflow is *very* different from a forum or a blog. The purpose of every question and its associated solutions is *primarily* to contribute to a library of problems and enlighten others. We are not here to answer each individual's problems; rather, we hope to find a catalogue of solutions. That means that every question should be unique (it is why we have a category of reasons for deletion that an equivalent question has been resolved before) and cannot refer to any other post except to point out a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's stored in a per-interpreter hash keyed by the address of the opcode (`MY_CXT.x_GLOB_ENTRIES` in `ext/File-Glob/Glob.xsglob.xs`).

The fact that it's keyed by the address of the opcode means two instances of the opcode in the source will have different iterators.

```
$ perl -E'say "".glob("{a,b}") for 1..2;'
a
b

$ perl -E'say "".glob("{a,b}"); say "".glob("{a,b}");'
a
a
```

The fact that it's per-interpreter means that each thread will have its own iterator for a given instance of the opcode.

```
$ perl -Mthreads -E'
   sub f { say "".glob("{a,b}"); }
   f() for 1..2;
'
a
b

$ perl -Mthreads -E'
   sub f { say "".glob("{a,b}"); }
   async { f() }->join for 1..2;
'
a
a
```

Comment: I understood that multiple calls to glob is being "saved", but not sure where/how between calls. Implied Stack pointer to a glob function in hash memory? Can't see it, bothers me.

Comment: It's not on the stack. That couldn't work. Has to be in the heap. C's heap, in this case.

Comment: How would it one the second call to function know where on the heap to go to reference the object previously created, up where it left off? When used outside of function, it works. So how is it different in memory?
ok...i see it know, wow...seriously, how would one know from docs

Comment: There's an entry in the hash for each op instance, keyed by the address of op instance. No two instances of an ops have the same address, and the address of the op never changes.

Comment: perl -E'sub in_function{ say "".glob("{a,b}"); } in_function(); in_function();' => a
b
another illustration.